# using jquery to pass value to constructor on rendered attribute

Tags: jquery

I am trying to populate a field in my vf page based on id stored in an hidden input field. I tried using the onchange attribute for inputText but it didn't work. I am now trying to use jquery to access the id, pass it as an actionfunction to the controller and then do the necessary dml. Could anyone point to me what i'm doing wrong?

```
<apex:form id="theForm">
<apex:pagemessages/>
<apex:actionFunction reRender="noOfGuest" name="changeNumberOfGuest" action="{!checkGuests2}">
    <apex:param assignTo="{!productId}" name="noGuestAssign" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>
    <apex:pageBlock id="pB" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:inputField value="{!tix.Attendee__c}" required="true"/>
            <apex:inputText size="30" id="targetName" value="{!tix.Ticket_Type__c}" required="true" disabled="true" style="position: relative; right: 43px" styleClass="greenHighlight">
                <a href="#" onclick="openLookupPopup('{!$Component.targetName}', '{!$Component.targetId}'); return false" style="position: relative; left: 260px" id="targethRefId">Lookup</a>
            </apex:inputText>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:inputField value="{!tix.Event__c}" required="true"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!tix.Aux_TicketNo__c}" label="Quantity" style="width:25px" required="true"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:inputField value="{!tix.Booker__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!tix.Ticket_Type__r.No_of_Guests__c}" id="noOfGuest"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <div style="float:right; margin-top:20px">
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" styleClass="but" oncomplete="window.parent.location.href = '/{!EvntId}'"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!createAttendee}" styleClass="but"/>
            <apex:inputHidden value="{!eventId}" id="targetId"/>
        </div>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

What i'm basically trying to do here is populate the tix.Ticket_Type__r.No_of_Guests__c field with the correct number everytime the tix.Attendee__c has been updated. Here is the jquery:

```
    var newWin=null;
    function openLookupPopup(name, id){
        var theId = '{!evnt.Id}';
        var url="/apex/LookupEventPopup?namefield=" + name + "&idfield=" + id + '&eveId=' + theId;
        newWin=window.open(url, 'Popup','height=500,width=900,left=100,top=100,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');
        if (window.focus){
            newWin.focus();
        }
        return false;
    }

    function closeLookupPopup(){
        if (null!=newWin){
            newWin.close();
        }
    }

    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).on('change', '[id$="targetName"]', function() {
        alert('yay!');
        changeNumberOfGuest($j("input[id$='targetId']"));
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after many trials:

```
<apex:outputLabel value="Number Of Guest" for="tableRef" />
<apex:panelGrid columns="1" id="tableRefId">
    <apex:inputText size="10" value="{!eventId}" id="tableRef" disabled="true"/>
</apex:panelGrid>


    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    function closeLookupPopup(){
        if (null!=newWin){
            newWin.close();
            var productId = $j('[id$="targetId"]').val();
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                '{!$RemoteAction.AttendeeCreationEvent_Ctrl.getTableNumber}',
                productId,
                function(result, event) {
                    if(event.status) {
                        $j('input[id$="tableRef"]').val(result == 'null' ? 0 : result);
                    }
                }, {
                    escape: true
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

and in the constructor, just have a remote action that passes back the right value:

```
@RemoteAction
public static String getTableNumber(String prodId){
    return JSON.serialize([SELECT No_of_Guests__c FROM Product2 WHERE Id =: prodId].No_of_Guests__c);
}
```